# Saying Tachanun if there is a Kallah in the ladies section

Tags: halacha, women, wedding, tachanun

The Minhag is not to say Tachanun in a Minyan where there is a Chasan present. Suppose a Kallah came to Shul (and there is no Chasan present) for Shacharis or Mincha and is in the ladies section, do the men say Tachanun?

Comment: Was this inspired by my question!

Comment: @Yehoshua. Yes!

Comment: @GershonGold very interesting because I also though then to ask this after hearing this malacha shailo today...

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30810

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Shevet HaLevi 5:12 - end of Teshuva](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1415&st=&pgnum=18) says that a Kallah in the Ezras Nashim would not be sufficient reason not to say Tachanun since she is not combined with the Minyan.

Comment: Does she exempt the women in the section with her?

Comment: @DoubleAA: I do not know as this is not discussed in the Teshuva.

Comment: What about a Chatan who is a Katan? He also does not combine with the minyan

Comment: @DoubleAA: Please let me know when you find such a Chatan.

Comment: I can do so, but I don't know why you want to know.

Comment: @C.BenYosef I knew a Katan whose marriage day was set a week before his bar mitzva.

Comment: In the Koren siddur, IIRC, it says in its instructions, "some say a Kallah, also". I don't know who "some" is.

Comment: Is the operant here that she's a woman or that she's a woman and therefore physically separated from the functioning minyan?