# Berith Millah in a different section of the Shul - Do you say Tahanun?

Tags: halacha, synagogue, brit-milah, minyan, tachanun

Are you supposed to say Tahanun if there is a Berith Millah being held in a different section of the Shul (eg., different Minyan being held in a different room)?

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30809

Answer (score 5):

[Birchei Yosef 131](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7626&st=&pgnum=72) says that unless there is a clear Minhag not to, a seperate room would say Tachanun.